# Missing comma before start of a new alter operation

Tags: mysql

I am writing a simple query in PHPMyAdmin

```
 alter TABLE testing_database RENAME COLUMN name TO first_name;
```

and in here error has been occurring

> Missing comma before start of a new alter operation. (near "TO" at position 52)

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? `RENAME COLUMN` was added in 8.0.

Comment: I am using version 8.0, if I use change in the place of rename same error is occurring again.

Comment: I don't think you are. I just tested your code, and it works in 8.0, but gets that error in 5.7.

Comment: Actually, it gets a different error in 5.7. But it still works in 8.0. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wcfg1aaBqRjN5A3AX4gnLd/1

Comment: Can't you just edit the table definition in PhpMyAdmin instead of doing this as a query? See https://my.bluehost.com/hosting/help/2155#targetText=To%20the%20right%20of%20the,%2C%20default%20value%2C%20and%20more.

Comment: yes I can but I got the solution thanks for your time sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE testing_database CHANGE `name` `first_name` data_type;
```